# Trying to connect to port 449 using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect to a URL that contains a port number (449) using cURL emulating a browser.

After two days of trying, all I can get is "Error #7, Failed to connect to www.atomy.com port 449: Connection timed out"

This is my most recent attempt...

```
$url="https://www.atomy.com:449/us/Home/Account/Login";
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0';
$header=array(
  'Host: www.atomy.com:449',
  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0',
  'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
  'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br',
  'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
  'Keep-Alive: 300',
  'Connection: keep-alive',
  'DNT: 1',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
  'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '449');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // don't return headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

echo 'error no: '.curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo 'error: '.curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
curl_close ($ch);
die();
exit();
```

More code follows in which I will be using simple_html_dom.php to retrieve hidden form values before submitting a login form.

But I need to get past this before I can even think about form submission.

Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions.

PS: The url is an asp.net page. Not sure if that's important or not.

Comment: Try removing the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '449');` line

Comment: @BubbleHacker - thanks, but same result

Comment: so I tried the code and seems to work for me (although it returns weird Unicode characters). Maybe the port is blocked? Are you using a cloud or hosting service?

Comment: I also tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);` ... but I still get the same results

Comment: @BubbleHacker - can I ask what browser and OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome, but the browser doesn't matter since the request is in the server side...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130869/discussion-between-kuya-and-bubble-hacker).

Comment: @BubbleHacker - Thank you for your discussion/chat. It seems my host server was blocking outgoing calls to port 449. They opened the port and now (just like you) I get a bunch of unicode characters.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help!